# Is this an Improper use of CountdownLatch with initial count = 1

Tags: java, multithreading

Below is the snippet, listing 5.11 from book 'java concurrency in practice' by Brain Goetz.

I find the below code confusing. It seems that countdownlatch 'startGate' has a flawed usage. ( 'endGate' usage is OK )

```
public class TestHarness {
public long timeTasks(int nThreads, final Runnable task)
        throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch startGate = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch endGate = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startGate.await();
                    try {
                        task.run();
                    } finally {
                        endGate.countDown();
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    startGate.countDown();
    endGate.await();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    return end - start;
}
```

}

Execution of line `startGate.countDown()` will notify all the worker threads waiting on the latch. But is this guaranteed to notify all the nThreads ?
It is quite possible only a few threads, say 2 threads, out nTheads have executed startGate.await() call of the run() method. 
And at this time the main thread executes `startGate.countDown()`. This call will notify only the 2 threads ( out of nThreads ) waiting on the latch.

Now the rest of the other threads ( nThread - 2 ) will call `startGate.await()` later in time, but as the main thread has already raised a notification, so the worker threads( nThreads- 2) will now wait indefinitely for notification ?

Or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once `startGate.countDown();` is called the count is zero (because it started at one). Any subsequent calls to `startGate.await();` ... don't wait; it's been counted down to zero.

From the [Javadocs for `CountDownLatch.await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await%28%29):

> If the current count is zero then this method returns immediately.

A `CountDownLatch` is used to block threads only until some work in another thread(s) is completed. Once that work is completed, the latch is counted down to zero allowing any waiting or future threads to continue past it.

Comment: @Brain: yes true. CountDownLatch.await() blocks only as long as the count > 0. For count=0, it simply returns. await() method appeared confusing because of my undue comparisons with Object.wait().

Answer (score 1):

The CountDownLatch `countDown()` is *not like a notification* that can be missed but is like a ***Gate***. So once the gate is open it is open any time after. So the other threads which call `await()` will be directly allowed and ***not block***.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answers from @Brain and @Narendra. Having just gone through the source code of CountDownLatch and AbstractQueuedSynchroniser classes, I would like to add some more details. 
It is not a `wait()` and `notify()` based system, which I had mistakenly assumed because of the `CountdownLatch.await()`method.

- `CountdownLatch.countDown()` : If current count equals 0 , then it does nothing and simply returns. Otherwise, it first decreases the count by 1, and then checks if it 0. If 0 then it releases 'shared'.
- `CountdownLatch.await()` : Checks for the current count, if it equals 0 ( may be interrupted in between ), then it does nothing and simply returns. This method acquires 'shared' only when count > 0 ( or is not interrupted ).

It also appears that a declaration like `latch = new CountDownLatch(0)`, though harmless, but would be a worthless declaration, and should raise an Exception right in the constructor code, as it does for count < 0.

Comment: Raising an exception on 0 would unnecessarily complicate code, if the value is programmatically determined. There are cases where you don't need to wait for anything and as such, it would be annoying to have to construct with `1` only to immediately count down.

Comment: Yes quite true. I realized this much later when trying to implement a `rendezvous' between N threads using semaphores.